# Removing ???? or more with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, string

I would like to remove four or more question marks.

I'm using this right now:

```
preg_replace( '{\\?+}', '', $text );
```

but this does remove all question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Use {4,} to indicate 4 or more of the preceding thing
$pattern = '~\?{4,}~';

$str = "I have 3??? and that isn't enough";
$str2 = "I have 5????? and that is enough";

// Won't replace only 3 ?
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
// I have 3??? and that isn't enough

// Will replace 5 ?
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $str2);
// I have 5 and that is enough
```

Comment: In case you want to keep one question mark, replace the pattern with `"?"` instead of `""`.